# Finding the smallest set of rectangles that covers the given rectilinear simple polygons

Tags: algorithm, rectangles

For collision detection I'd like to turn a bitmap into a set of rectangles, using as few rectangles as possible. A more formal description of the problem is described in the title. An example:

[image: programmer art]

For tie-breakers of multiple solutions I'd prefer it if the total area covered by all the rectangles combined was maximized. For example, the blue rectangle in the above picture could've been smaller, but that would've been a less optimal solution.

Is there a more common name for this problem? Any literature? Or a simple algorithm that gives an optimal solution?

Comment: Your problem is not the same as, but looks very similar to the technique of using a Karnaugh map for boolean logic minimisation.  There is an automated algorithm for logic minimisation called the Quine–McCluskey algorithm.  I wonder if you had a look at extending it in a certain way, you might get somewhere.  Having said that, I might be talking a load of rubbish... :D

Comment: @NiklasB. That does generate a solution, but I'm not certain how I should optimize that to generate the optimal solution with the second constraint (the total area covered by all rectangles combined should be maximal). Oh and Aaron Dufour makes a good point about the cross.

Comment: @NiklasB. That's dissection into rectangles, not coverage by rectangles.  I didn't read the full solution, but it sounds like a distinctly different problem.

Comment: For example, a simple cross shape can be covered by two overlapping rectangles, but requires dissection into 3 rectangles.

Comment: @nightcracker I see, my reference indeed does not fit your problem

Comment: In that case the problem [seems to be NP-hard](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995884800121), so maybe you should look for a good approximation

Comment: I am working exactly on this problem, so far I didn't find an efficient method of finding optimal rectangles. I have implemented and improved a method similar to @David's answer, and it takes too long even for small instances. In which context are you trying to solve this?

Comment: @nimcap I solved the issue in a satisfactory way, see the answer I added. The context in which I was trying to solve the problem is generating quads from a bitmap for the collision map of a 2d platformer, for example http://imgur.com/PgjjaCL,JRuVqBx#0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in a way that was good enough - it's probably not optimal though.

1. Make a 2D array with the dimensions of the bitmap. For every pixel in the bitmap that's black make the corresponding element WALL, otherwise EMPTY_SPACE.
2. Scan the array left-right, top to bottom for the first EMPTY_SPACE. Save this coordinate.
3. Create a rectangle of area 1 with the topleft coordinate set to the coordinate found at 2, extending 1 downwards and to the right.
4. Horizontally extend the rectangle to the left and to the right as long as it doesn't cover any WALL.
5. Vertically extend the rectangle up and down as long as it doesn't cover any WALL.
6. Mark any element covered by the rectangle as a COVERED_SPACE and add the rectangle to the set of rectangles.
7. If there is still an element containing EMPTY_SPACE left goto 2, otherwise you're done.

Answer (score 4):

This problem may be NP-hard, but if you want the highest quality solutions for instances not created by an NP-hardness reduction, then running an [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) solver is worth a try. Even if running time is a concern, it may be useful to have a gold standard to compare against.

In essence you're trying to solve a special case of a problem called [set cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). This is how set cover can be formulated as an integer program.

```
minimize sum_{white rectangles R} x_R
subject to
for all white points p, sum_{white rectangles R such that p in R} x_R >= 1
for all white rectangles R, x_R in {0, 1}
```

All you have to do is write code to construct the specific instance of this integer program corresponding to its input, call the solver, get the results back, and then do one more optimization with the optimal number of rectangles (`k`) known.

```
maximize sum_{white rectangles R} area(R) x_R
subject to
for all white points p, sum_{white rectangles R such that p in R} x_R >= 1
for all white rectangles R, x_R in {0, 1}
sum_{white rectangles R} x_R <= k
```

If the instances are large, then you may need to do some preprocessing (the solvers typically can do this as well, but they have to use algorithms for a more general problem, which may not be as efficient). First, use only the white rectangles that are maximal, that is, are not contained in a larger white rectangle. There probably are clever algorithms for enumerating them, but you should implement the naive one and benchmark the whole system first. Second, use only some of the points. In particular, if p and q are distinct points, and p belongs to every maximal rectangle to which q belongs, then tracking p is superfluous.

Comment: The really nice thing about integer programming is that if you, for example, decide that you want to trade off covering some black pixels for a reduction in rectangles, then it's easier to fiddle with the program than it is to modify a custom algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest simply starting at an external corner which is not yet covered by a rectangle, and greedily growing that rectangle. Repeat until everything's covered. I don't think this gives you the tie-breaker property you're looking for on a global basis (since you may have multiple options for how to greedily grow each rectangle), but it does on a local basis.

Comment: @nightcracker sure it does. Just make sure you're searching the entire image for uncovered points.

Comment: @MarkRansom [Here is a counterexample.](http://i.imgur.com/pEI5Tdt.png) X will not be covered because no matter what corner you start from the algorithm will be greedy and take the long side.

Comment: Yeah, with holes you'd have to modify it to "start at an uncovered point, and greedily grow the rectangle". I'm not sure if that's optimal in number of rectangles... it might be.

Comment: @Sneftel It's probably not.

Comment: @Sneftel In my previous counterexample, even if you'd start at one of the corners of the hole you'd still not cover X, because it will grow alongside the long side (because it's larger).

Comment: @nightcracker if I'm understanding the algorithm it would work like this if searching is left-right/top-bottom: first rectangle upper part, second left part, third right part, fourth bottom part. And just because rectangle growth starts at an uncovered point doesn't mean it shouldn't include already covered points, so you get your overlap.

Comment: @nightcracker Choose an axis upfront along which to grow. Chose an uncovered point (preferrably a corner point). Greedily grow a rectangle along the chosen axis. Then greedily grow the rectangle along the other axis while possible. Repeat as long as you have uncovered points. I guess that would give you a rather good approximation (which is the best you can hope for, given that the problem is hard)

Comment: @NiklasB. Isn't growing alongside one axis first even worse? http://i.imgur.com/oFw64Ve.png

Comment: @nightcracker Well in this case it is even optimal (don't forget to grow along the other axis as well), but the sample is not very hard. Also, I meant choosing uncovered "pixels" at a corner, not uncovered corners